# (python) for loop operation 0 time, 1 time, many times differencate

Tags: python, python-3.x, for-loop, while-loop

**(python) for loop operation 0 time, 1 time, many times for creating several cv2.rectangle on same img**

I plan to draw square on original img show the part of duplicate, and if there is three, just over write 2 times of first original pic output, that should has 2 square though

I tried to commont every step in below script.

```
for k in range(len(list_for_duplicate_x_and_y)):

    # means no duplicate, don't need to draw square
    if len(list_for_duplicate_x_and_y) ==  0:
        print("ok no duplicate")

    # draw square on img "original_duplicate.png"
    elif len(list_for_duplicate_x_and_y) <  0:
        duplicate_xy = list_for_duplicate_x_and_y[k]
        duplicate_x = duplicate_xy[0]
        duplicate_y = duplicate_xy[1]
        k +=1
        img = cv2.imread("/home/student_DC/desktop/optimization_11_10/original_duplicate.png")
        duplicate_x = duplicate_x - 28
        duplicate_y = duplicate_y -54
        cv2.rectangle(img, (duplicate_x, duplicate_y), (duplicate_x + 92, duplicate_y + 82), (0, 255, 5), 5) 
        cv2.imwrite("/home/student_DC/desktop/optimization_11_10/original_duplicate_output.png" , img)

        # means 1 duplicate,  draw 1 square on duplicate part
        if len(list_for_duplicate_x_and_y) == 1:
            break

        # draw square on img "original_duplicate_output", and if there is three, just over write 2 times, should has 2 square
        # means n duplicate,  draw n square on duplicate part
        elif len(list_for_duplicate_x_and_y) < 1: 
            img = cv2.imread("/home/student_DC/desktop/optimization_11_10/original_duplicate_output.png")
            duplicate_x = duplicate_x - 28
            duplicate_y = duplicate_y -54
            cv2.rectangle(img, (duplicate_x, duplicate_y), (duplicate_x + 92, duplicate_y + 82), (0, 255, 5), 5) 
            cv2.imwrite("/home/student_DC/desktop/optimization_11_10/original_duplicate_output.png" , img)
```

**Question: how to circle out the mutiple green square, my output is always one square**

here is the output pic: https://i.stack.imgur.com/94W7N.jpg

(ps.) I guess is line 25 `elif len(list_for_duplicate_x_and_y) < 1:` need to change something, can someone just give me a hand, thanks.

Comment: You don't need those if statements at all.  You're in a `for` loop based on the length of that list.  If the length is zero, the loop is not going to run.  And a length can never be `< 0`.

Comment: yeah, thanks , I see where the problem is

Comment: @Tim Roberts if you want you can post your tip as answer, and I can mark as solve

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need those `if` statements at all. You're in a `for` loop based on the length of that list. If the length is zero, the loop is not going to run. And a length can never be `< 0`.